# Let $x,y$ be positive real numbers. Then $x<y$ iff $x^n<y^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: inequality, induction, real-numbers

I tried proving it but I'm quite skeptical about it:

$(\Rightarrow )$ Assume $x<y$. Clearly, the base case for the induction is done. Assume $x^k<y^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.  Now, $x^{k+1}=x^k\cdot x<y^k\cdot y=y^{k+1}$.

$(\Leftarrow )$ Assume for contradiction that $x\not< y$. Then $y\le x$. Now, suppose $y\ne x$. Then $y<x$. It follows that $y^n<x^n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ from $(\Rightarrow )$. This contradicts our hypothesis. Also, if $y\not< x$ then $x=y$. Then $y^n=x^n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ which also contradicts our hypothesis.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The direction $\Leftarrow$ is trivial by taking $n=1$... (But your arguments are fine)

Comment: In regards to Yanko's comment.  I think a stronger statement and perhaps the statement you were actually meant to prove was $x< y \iff \exists k\in \mathbb N; x^k < y^k \iff \forall n \in \mathbb N; x^n < y^n$.  Admitted 3=> 1or 3=> 2 and 1=> 2 are trivial but 2=>1 (or 2=>3) will require the proof by contradiction argument you did correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For an approach without induction note that $$ y^n - x^n = (y-x) \left(y^{n-1}+y^{n-2}x+\dots+yx^{n-2}+x^{n-1} \right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Much more is true.

If
$x > 0, y>0$
then
$x < y
\iff
x^n < y^n
$
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The proof both ways
depends on
$x^n-y^n
=(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ky^{n-1-k}
$
and
$x>0, y>0
\implies \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^ky^{n-1-k}
 > 0
$.

Note that
this implies that
$x-y$
and
$x^n-y^n$
have the same sign
(+, -, or $0$).