# Prove that if $x^n < y^n \Rightarrow x < y$, for $x,y > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I already have the demonstration that $x > y$ implies that $x^{n} > y^{n}$ for $x$ and $y$ positives and I read that to prove the inverse way I could use the contrapositive form but this would give me that $x^{n} \le y^n \Rightarrow x\le y$ not $x^n < y^n\Rightarrow x<y$. So, how can I prove this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $x,y$ be positive real numbers. Then $x<y$ iff $x^n<y^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782762/let-x-y-be-positive-real-numbers-then-xy-iff-xnyn-for-all-n-in-math)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x,y>0$ and $x^n<y^n$.

Since you've already shown that $x>y>0$ implies that $x^n>y^n$, we can't have $x>y$.

Similarly, if $x=y$, then $x^n=y^n$, so we can't have $x=y$ either.

Since one of the following holds:

$$x>y$$
$$x=y$$
$$x<y$$

it must be the case that $x<y$.